# Place random object on ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, random

I have and ArrayList of objects and i want to randomly rearrange the objects.

```
 ArrayList<someobject> arr = new ArrayList<someobject>();
```

Is there a java function, or i have to implement my own ?

Comment: 1. you probably mean: `Object` not `object`. 2. using `Object` is a bad idea - you lose all the type safety that the compiler provides. 3. In Java 9 you can do: `List.of(object1, object2, object3, ...)` see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of-E-

Comment: There is no pre-defined methods for randomly initializing a list, or a collection. ("Random" means different things in different contexts.) You'll need to do it yourself.

Comment: what about the collections.shuffle(); ?? could that be used to randomly rearrange the objects ? ..I should define that when i say objects i mean objects of a class(sorry for missing that)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of code that will accomplish your task:

```
public static ArrayList<Object> getObjectArray(int size, int low, int high) {

    ArrayList<Object> objList = new ArrayList<>();
    Random rand = new Random();
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        int randomNum = rand.nextInt((high - low) + 1) + low;
        objList.add(randomNum);
    }
    return objList;
}
```

The code will take create an ArrayList of Integer's (which are Objects) of specified size, where it's members are random numbers between low and high.

An aside- You'll notice that "randomNum" is of type int- these randomNums are converted into Integers via boxing, which are different variable types. "int" is not an Object (it's a primitive data type), but "Integer" is.